# CodeIgniter: howto override Pagination configuration in controller code?

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I recently jumped on the CodeIgniter train because I finally want to embrace the MVC architecture for my growing PHP/MySQL projects.
Right now I encounter a probolemin the PAgination configuratino that is apparently not described earlier as far as I can ssee.

Probably the issue is not PAgination only related but more general. In my first attempt, I just filled the confiuration in the controller method and passed it to the initialize() method:

```
$config['base_url'] = $this->config->base_url() .  "/categorie/{$catName}/";
$config['total_rows'] =      $this->event_model->get_nrofevents_for_categorie($categorieObject->id, TRUE);
$config['per_page'] = 12;
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="paging">';
$config['full_Tag_close'] = '</div>';
$config['prev_link'] = 'Vorige';
$config['next_link'] = 'Volgende';
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

And this works fine. But I have a buch of other pages that use the same pagination with most of its parameteres identical, only the base_url and the total_rows config properties are different for each page.
I have put the common  configuration in the config/pagination.php configuration file but see no option to add the page-dependent properties in the code.
More general, is it possible to put generic configuration in a config file and add some customized properties in the controller method?
For me this seems logical but cannot figure out how...
I tried something like:

```
$this->load->config('pagination');
$this->config->set_item('next_link', 'blablabla');
```

but it seems that the Pagination is initialized immediately after reading the config file and this code has no effect.
Please any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

Since the `initialize()` only replaces the keys you provide, you can have your `config/pagination.php` hold the default values and call `initialize()` with the changing ones.

#### config/pagination.php

```
 // put default values here
 $config['next_link'] = 'Volgende';
 $config['prev_link'] = 'Vorige';
 // ...
```

#### controller

```
 $this->pagination->initialize(array(
     'base_url' => base_url().'categorie/'.$catName.'/',
     'total_rows' => $totalRows,
      // ...
 )));
```

Comment: So this means that I will not use the Pagination.php config file, which is apparently used by the Pagination class automatically?

Comment: Yes, if you copy the example then you won't. But since the `initialize()` [only copies over the keys you provide](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Pagination.php#L115) to the defaults, it should work without explicitly merge in the `$this->config->item('pager')` array.

Comment: I've redid the answer, making a separate config array proved to be superfluous.

Comment: Seems to work indeed, so thanks! 
Having some of the pagination parameters in the config file, I need to read them to pass into the querymethod in the model:
$this->load->config('pagination');
$per_page = $this->config->item('per_page');
(this value is passed as the limit parameter)

Seems to work OK but it is not fully clear how to use $this->config, does it always refer to the last loaded configuration file?

Comment: This is clear now too after reading the documentation once more :) Loading a config file just add the configdata to the config array, in case of possible name conflits a second parameter can be used.

Answer (score 0):

don't use base_url()... I always use site_url();

```
$config['base_url'] = site_url('');
```